# How do I reactivate wheel and everyone on osx maverick for HD

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-mavericks, sharing

I updated to osx Mavericks a few weeks ago. Since then my computer crashed about three times; a computer that never crashed before. Anyway, today someone on my network told me they are able to browse through my entire HD because I am sharing it. But when I look through the `System Preferences > Sharing`, as expected, I am only actually sharing one very specific folder called `ourproject_2`. So it made no sense to me that my HD was being shared with everyone on the network. Then I go to the `HD`, clicked on `Get Info` and then under `Sharing and Permissions` I saw `System, wheel, and Everyone`. Not wanting my `HD` shared with everyone, I remove `everyone` and then `wheel` since I had no idea who wheel was.

Now my computer is practically frozen. I cannot open anything, I cannot right click, I am stuck. So my question is: does anyone know how I might reactivate (if that's the correct term) `wheel` and `everyone`

Comment: The "Sharing & Permissions" info dialog has very little to do with what "shares" you are advertising to the world. "`wheel`" and "`everyone`" read permission are kinda required for the OS to function as normal. Try to run "Disk Utility"'s "Repair Permissions" from our OS or boot into single user mode or recovery mode and run that "Repair Permissions" from that recovery mode startup.

Comment: `"Disk Utility"'s "Repair Permissions"` is that a CD that was supposed to come with my computer? I will search on the internet, but since you mention it, maybe you can tell me a bit more. thanks.

Comment: btw @hrbrmstr right now my computer, when I try to start it, simply stays on the grey page with the apple logo showing. Nothing more.

Comment: Immediately hold down Command-R after startup until the gray Apple logo appears. A few moments later, you’ll see an OS X Utilities window that tells indicates Recovery Mode. If that doesn’t work for any reason, choose try holding down Option after reboot until a list of startup volumes appears. Select Recovery… and press Return

Comment: @hrbrmstr will I lose my data if I reinstall OS X through the recovery? from your instructors and searched and read http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718 but it does not say.

Comment: with your help I was able to turn a bad day into a good one: all is well that ends well, no? So many thanks, @hrbrmstr. Will you please rewrite your comment as a response. Basically, the recovery option worked for me (I did everything, but the `Disk Utility` failed). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That just happened to me and all you need to do to fix it is:

- Boot your machine while pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Reinstall Mac OS X

After that the permissions will be back and you will be able to enter your session again, with all your data!